# Get an array column based on the values of another column in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have a multi-column PHP array as

```
Array (
    Array ('col1', 'col2', 'col3'),
);
```

How can I get an array of `col2` if `col1` is greater than a specific value?

I can do it by a `foreach` loop, but I think it should be possible with a native function like `array_filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you're better with a foreach loop, as you're not going to have to make multiple iterations of the array. You want to both filter and modify the array, which requires using both `array_filter()` and `array_map()` in order to get what you want:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    [5, 'col2-1', 'col3'],
    [10, 'col2-2', 'col3']
];

$res = array_filter($arr, function($item) {
    return $item[0] > 7;
});

$res = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item[1];
}, $res);

var_dump($res);
```

Test here: https://3v4l.org/HRTOJ